# DRF detail Not found

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am working on a project that returns some metrics from a text. 
The user is to enter the text in a textbox and the results are displayed to the user.
My serializers.py

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from .models import Entryt

class CreateEntrySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entryt
        fields = ('text',)

class EntryDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Entryt
        fields = ('sentence_count', 'flesch_ease', 'flesch_grade', 'smog', 'linsear', 'text_standard')
    lookup_field = 'pk'
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView, RetrieveAPIView
from .serializers import EntryDetailSerializer, CreateEntrySerializer, Entryt


class CreateEntryView(CreateAPIView):
    model = Entryt
    serializer_class = CreateEntrySerializer
    queryset = Entryt.objects.all()


class ResultView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = EntryDetailSerializer
    queryset = Entryt.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import ResultView, CreateEntryView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', CreateEntryView.as_view(), name='create'),
    url(r'^result/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', ResultView.as_view(), name='result'),
]
```

http://localhost:8000/flesch/result/2/ url like this show's nothing though there is an item with that id in the db.

How do I go about fixing this and any tips on making the code better would be great.

Comment: add line in `ResultView`:  `Print queryset`
you are just saving objects in `queryset` and doing nothing with `queryset`

Comment: Next you can get `id` in view and use `Entryt.objects.filter(id=2)` and it will give you required results

Comment: same error. I tried overriding the `get_queryset` method and had the same error

Comment: are you getting any error ? or you are getting nothing ?
if you are getting error then share your error.

Comment: `  detail: Not found `